# What variable type do firebase images have?

Tags: swift, firebase, types

Trying to declare a global variable to a firebase image in swift, but don't know its type.

```
var imageRef: UIImage
var imageRef: Data
```

Nope, doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, the variable is referring to an image in storage:        imageRef = storageRef.child("image/IMG_0007.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: 
    var imageRef: StorageReference